# How to add a favicon as a package resource to the header section in Wicket 8?

Tags: wicket, favicon

The way how resources should be added to the header section in *Wicket 8* is described in the *Reference Guide* in the chapter [Adding resources to page header section](https://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/guide/8.x/single.html#_adding_resources_to_page_header_section%22Adding%20resources%20to%20page%20header%20section%22).

In my application, I'm adding the CSS and JavaScript as *package resources* in following way:

```java
public class BasePage extends WebPage {

    @Override
    public void renderHead(IHeaderResponse response) {
        super.renderHead(response);

        ResourceReference regisCssRef =
                new PackageResourceReference(getClass(), "static/css/regis.css");
        response.render(CssHeaderItem.forReference(regisCssRef));

        ResourceReference jqueryJSRef =
                new PackageResourceReference(getClass(), "static/js/jquery.min.js");
        response.render(JavaScriptHeaderItem.forReference(jqueryJSRef));
    }
}
```

My question is: **how to add a *favicon.ico* resource in the similar way?** So, as a resource created with usage of the `PackageResourceReference` class.

Answer (score 2):

There is a [MetaDataHeaderItem](https://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/8.x/org/apache/wicket/markup/head/MetaDataHeaderItem.html) class for purpose of `<meta>` and `<link>` elements. Unfortunately, it doesn't support *package resources* and in fact, any `ResourceReference` - it misses the method `forReference()`.

I was able to solve my problem with following code, but not sure that's a nice solution:

```java
ResourceReference faviconRef =
        new PackageResourceReference(
                getClass(), "static/images/favicon.ico");
response.render(
        MetaDataHeaderItem.forLinkTag("shortcut icon",
                                      urlFor(faviconRef, null).toString()));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `MetaDataHeaderItem` class:

```
response.render(MetaDataHeaderItem.forLinkTag("icon", "static/fav.ico"));
```

Comment: Yes, I checked the `MetaDataHeaderItem` class. Unfortunately, it doesn't support *package resources*, but just strings (or string models).